# existence and uniqueness of reaction diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am trying to prove uniqueness of equation of the form
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)
$$

Can anyone suggest the standard literature for existence and uniqueness for equation like above?

Comment: Maybe this link could be useful (page 52) http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/techno/user_files/tse/nonlinpde.pdf

Comment: thanks. I have seen this. But I don't know which fixed point theorem to apply for RD(system).

Comment: Literature depends on the assumptions for $f(u)$. What assumptions on $f$ do you have?

Comment: case 1: $f$ locally lipschitz continuous